# Tub surrond caulking question

Tags: grout, caulking, tub, silicone

My contractor just completed replacing the tub surround. the walls are tiled from the tub to the ceiling.

A few things I'm not too sure about, and would like to get some opinions.

1. The contractor did not silicon caulk the edge between the upper tile wall and ceiling. Just grout it. Granted, due to some shifting walls, the ceiling needs to be repainted in spring and you can't paint on silicon caulking. Just wondering if the lack of caulking would cause issues.
2. The silicone caulking was applied to the tub edges while the grout was not fully dry (he did it about an hour or so after he finished grouting). It has been about 8 hours now, While all the other grouts have dried and lightened, the ones under the clear caulking is still dark. Would the calking interfere with the grout curing process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Number 1**

It could cause a problem, however it it unlikely. Use the shower a few times, and see what kind of condensation settles on the wall above the tiles. If you can see visible droplets of water beading on the wall, you will have a problem over time. As your house settles, and expands/contracts over time the grout will develop fine cracks. These droplets will over time go behind your tiles, and weaken the structure of your wall. If it was cement board it probably wont even matter, and we are talking decades before damage here, but why take the chance for a $5 tube of caulk? There are several brands of caulking meant for the bathroom that can be painted.

Tip - when you apply caulk and run your finger over the caulk to get a smooth surface, make sure your finger is wet first. Makes a huge improvement to how the caulk spreads and looks.

**Number 2**

The silicone will affect the drying of the grout, and you will probably find it takes well over a week to match the color of other grout. Depending on how good the seal is (i.e. is the grout exposed to air or a porous surface underneath), it could take a very long time. I wouldn't worry about it other than for cosmetic reasons.

Answer (score -2):

No problems. Though I would suggest a putting a sealer on all that grout.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's a bit tough to understand what your answer is supposed to mean; a few more supporting sentences and context would help.